# bread crumb on click functionality

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am developing angular chartjs application which has dynamic pie charts when clicked on a pie chart. I want to have a bread crumb on top of pie charts, so the user knows the hierarchy of pie charts, what he had clicked.

I want to implement on click functionality for bread crumbs so when clicked on each bread crumb, I want to make visible of that specific pie chart.

I have tried on click functionality for bread crumb, but on click does not work. 
Can any one help on that.

Component.html

```
<nav aria-label='breadcrumb'>
        <ol class='breadcrumb'>
          <li *ngFor='let breadcrumb of breadCrumbs'>
            <a onclick="handleBreadCrumb()">{{ breadcrumb.label}}</a>
            <!-- [routerLink]='[breadcrumb.url, breadcrumb.params]' routerLinkActive='active' -->
          </li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
```

component.ts

```
handleBreadCrumb = function() {
    alert("bread crumb clicked.");
  }
```

This function is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the function declaration in the Angular way.

Try like this:

Template:

```
<a (click)="handleBreadCrumb()">{{ breadcrumb.label}}</a>
```

component.ts

```
handleBreadCrumb() {
  alert("bread crumb clicked.");
}
```

Comment: My Bad. forgot angular way of binding. Thanks Adritha, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

.html file

```js
<li *ngFor='let breadcrumb of breadCrumbs'> // add active class here
            <a onclick="handleBreadCrumb()">{{ breadcrumb.label}}</a>
</li>
```

.ts file

```js
handleBreadCrumb(){
     alert('do some stuff');
}
```